# Limit length of first excerpt in the loop

Tags: functions, loop, excerpt

Searched everywhere but have not seem this come up. I'm looking to set the length of the excerpts in the loop in `functions.php` but I need the first post only to have double the characters as the rest.

Example: 1st post set to 60 characters, following posts set to 30.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) 
{
    static $instance = 0;
    return ( in_the_loop() && 0 == $instance++ ) ? 60 : 30;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length' );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine where you are inside the loop in this filter, you will have to access the [global main query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Misc). Like this:

```
add_filter ('excerpt_length', 'wpse268679_custom_excerpt_length');

function wpse268679_custom_excerpt_length ($length) {
  // access main query
  global $wp_query;
  // do this only for the main loop and the first post in the query
  if (is_main_query() && ($wp_query->current_post == 0))
    $length = 60;
  else
    $length = 30;
  return $length;
  }
```

The above will work for the main loop only. If you have a local loop, you cannot access the query globally, so you will have to build your own excerpt function, which passes the query in stead of the post. This isn't that difficult. Like this:

```
 wpse268679_custom_excerpt ($query) {
   if ($query->current_post == 0)
     $excerpt = wp_trim_words ($query->post->post_excerpt, 60);
   else
     $excerpt = wp_trim_words ($query->post->post_excerpt, 30);
   return $excerpt;
   }
```

Beware that above will need tweaking, for instance to take into account cases where there is no excerpt defined (in which case you may want to use the post content to trim).

Comment: Thanks for this really useful particularly about the global variable. The codex mentions only using the variables listed, would this approach be considered good practice. I'm just learning and don't want to pick up bad habits : ) Testing now will mark correct shortly.

Comment: It does not seem to affect the first post? Only this variable is having an effect and it affects all the posts?  `$length = 30;`

Comment: I've tested this in my own install and it works. Possibly some plugin is messing with the excerpt. Are you sure the filter is called at all?

Comment: No plugins yet its a fresh _s theme. Got the excerpts showing correctly originally with this query: 

`function small_excerpt_length( $length ) {
 return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'small_excerpt_length' );
` so I removed it and added your code. There are multiple loops on the page but that shouldnt matter should it? It should affect the first post of each loop?

Comment: So, the filter is called. Try echoing something inside the condition to see if it is applied correctly

Comment: Condition has no result in the first part of the statement. There are multiple loops on the page like this : https://codepen.io/whispering_jack/pen/YVmrZx

Comment: Right. Those are local loops (with locally generated instances of `wp_query`), so you cannot access them globally. In that case your best course of action is to build a custom excerpt function.

Comment: Ok that explains that. So im basically back at square one. Can you provide an example by any chance?

Comment: Example added, but will need some extra work

Comment: Thank heaps. Does this go in the loop or in functions.php?

Comment: The function goes in `functions.php` and you call it from the loop in stead of `get_the_excerpt`,

Comment: Like this: `<div class="entry-content">
 
  <span class="entry-text"> 
   <?php wpse268679_custom_excerpt( $query ) ?> 
  </span>
 </div><!-`. I just cannot get this to work!

Comment: In the codepen you give the query is called `$q`, not `$query` as in my example.

Comment: Ah dang. Thanks for picking that up. Id been up for two days at that point thanks for helping out again.